# Limitations on sending through UDP sockets

Tags: c++, udp

I have a big 1GB file, which I am trying to send to another node. After the sender sends 200 packets (before sending the complete file) the code jumps out. Saying "Sendto no send space available". What can be the problem and how to take care of it.

Apart from this, we need maximum throughput in this transfer. So what send buffer size we should use to be efficient?

What is the maximum MTU which we can use to transfer the file without fragmentation?

Thanks
Ritu

---

Thank you for the answers. Actually, our project specifies to use UDP and then some additional code to take care of lost packets.

Now I am able to send the complete file, using blocking UDP sockets.

I am running the whole setup on an emulab like environment, called deter. I have set link loss to 0 but still my some packets are getting lost. What could be the possible reason behind that? Even if I add delay (assuming receiver drops the packet when its buffer is full) after sending every packet..still this packet losts persists.

Comment: Need more details.  Is the socket non-blocking?

Comment: I would think that TCP would be a better choice for file transfer.  Is there a reason that you are using UDP?  If so, do you have some kind of error correction?

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to use UDP for high speed data transfer, but you have to make sure not to send() the data out faster than your network card can pump it onto the wire.  In practice that means either using blocking I/O, or blocking on select() and only sending the next packet when select() indicates that the socket is ready-for-write.  (ideally you'd also not send the data faster than the receiving machine can receive it, but that's less of an issue these days since modern CPU speeds are generally much faster than modern network I/O speeds)

Once you have that logic working properly, the size of your send-buffer isn't terribly important.  (i.e. your send buffer will never be large enough to hold a 1GB file anyway, so making sure your program doesn't overflow the send buffer is the key issue whether the send buffer is large or small)  The size of the receive-buffer on the receiver is important though... best to make that as large as possible, so the receiving computer won't drop packets if the receiving process gets held off of the CPU by another program.

Regarding MTU, if you want to avoid packet fragmentation (and assuming your packets are traveling over Ethernet), then you shouldn't place more than 1468 bytes into each UDP packet (or 1452 bytes if you're using IPv6).  (Calculated by subtracting the size of the necessary IP and UDP headers from Ethernet's 1500-byte frame size)

Answer (score 2):

Also agree with @jonfen. No UDP for high speed file transfer.

UDP incur less protocol overhead. However, at the maximum transfer rate, transmit errors are inevitable (such as packet loss). So one must incorporate TCP like error correction scheme. End result is lower than TCP performance.